# android DatePicker don't update after setMinDate (setMaxDate)

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm creating dialog for pick date range. I have view where they are two DatePickers and each min and max date depends from other current selected date.

here is part of my code.

```
  public void initialize(OnDateRangeSelectedListener callback, Calendar currentStartDate, Calendar currentEndDate) {
    onDateRangeSelectedListener = callback;

    if (currentStartDate == null){
        this.currentStartDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    } else {
        this.currentStartDate = currentStartDate;
    }

    if (currentEndDate == null){
        this.currentEndDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    } else {
        this.currentEndDate = currentEndDate;
    }
}

public interface OnDateRangeSelectedListener {
    void onTimeRangeSelected(Calendar startDate, Calendar endDate);
}

public void setOnDateRangeSetListener(OnDateRangeSelectedListener callback) {
    onDateRangeSelectedListener = callback;
}

DatePicker startDatePicker, endDatePicker;

Calendar currentStartDate;
Calendar currentEndDate;

private DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener dateChangedListener = new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.startDatePicker:
                currentStartDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                break;
            case R.id.endDatePicker:
                currentEndDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (startDatePicker != null && endDatePicker != null) {
            startDatePicker.setMaxDate(currentEndDate.getTimeInMillis());
            endDatePicker.setMinDate(currentStartDate.getTimeInMillis());
        }
    }
};


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_range_picker_dialog, container, false);
    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    tabs = (TabHost) root.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    setDateRange = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.bSetDateRange);


    startDatePicker = (DatePicker) root.findViewById(R.id.startDatePicker);
    startDatePicker.init(currentStartDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            currentStartDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            currentStartDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
            dateChangedListener);
    startDatePicker.setMaxDate(currentEndDate.getTimeInMillis());


    endDatePicker = (DatePicker) root.findViewById(R.id.endDatePicker);
    endDatePicker.init(currentEndDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            currentEndDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            currentEndDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
            dateChangedListener);
    endDatePicker.setMinDate(currentStartDate.getTimeInMillis());
```

when I choose some date DatePickers   don't update and max(min) date stays the same.

how can I update my Datepicker views after chose some day.

sorry for my bad english )))